# Could not open builtin file modules.builtin.bin

Tags: drivers, modprobe, fuse

I was trying to run **modprobe fuse**.

But could not get it to run. The output -

```
sudo modprobe fuse
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:508 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file() 
could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab104.1/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found.
```

Even tried to update the kernel using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic
```

but that did not help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a mismatch between which kernel version modprobe is looking for `2.6.32-042stab104.1` vs the version you have (re)installed `3.19.0-30-generic`.

use `uname -r` to dump your running kernel.  It looks like you have some custom kernel installed - check your bootloader (probably grub) to see if it is hardcoded to some ancient kernel instead of the lastest installed kernel.

2.6.32 is old (ancient) enough that it probably doesn't use modules.builtin.bin - so you may have a mismatch in your modutils version vs your kernel