# Unable to mount sftp drive using sshfs - could not open builtin file

Tags: kernel, mount, sftp, sshfs, modprobe

I'm trying to mount sftp drives to my box (Ubuntu trusty - yes I know its old) however I'm getting an issue whenever I try

Output from `sshfs command fuse`:

```
device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

Output of `modprobe fuse`

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:507 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab113.11/modules.builtin.bin'
```

I understand this can be caused by a kernel mismatch (referenced from here: [Could not open builtin file modules.builtin.bin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687369/could-not-open-builtin-file-modules-builtin-bin)),

so: Output of `uname -a output`

```
Linux <hostname> 2.6.32-042stab113.11 #1 SMP Fri Dec 18 17:32:04 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So it looks like its trying to load the file from the right kernel, so I'm really stuck as to what to do.

I'm reluctant to do a release upgrade as last time I did this I basically ended up rebuilding all the services I had running on the box.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running? 2.6.32 is ancient.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS - I haven't upgraded because last time I did it trashed the whole setup and I had to spend days reinstalling.